# Using bold math with mtpro2 lite

Tags: math-mode, bold, mtpro

By using the "lite" version of the MathTime Professional II fonts, and correspondingly loading the `mtpro2` package I only get a "poor-man's" bold math type. Is it possible to have a "true" bold math type visually consistent with those Times-based fonts and still use those math fonts in their "lite" version?

As for the MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
This is an example of poor-man's bold math: $\bm k$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The lite version doesn't provide bold math. You have to buy the full version.

Comment: Is it possible nevertheless switching to use bold math from the alphabet defined in another Times-based math package such as  `newtxmath`?

Comment: I doubt it: `mtpro2` uses its own font encodings.